# Reasons for Empty Dataset

Tags: google-bigquery

Can you please explain the possible reasons that I'm unable to view the schema of a .csv dataset that I'm attempting to import (from a local file) into bq.  The table name and icon appear in the left pane, but when I click on the table icon, I don't see a schema similar to the ones for the sample datasets.  As far as I can tell, I'm correctly inputting the schema for each field name.

Answer (score 1):

While the table is importing, it may show up in the left hand pane without a schema. If the import fails, then you'll never get a real table to be populated there. If you click on the job history link on the upper right side of the page, you should see your load job and you can see whether it succeeded or failed. If it failed, you should be able to click on it and see the errors from the job.

Comment: Jordan-  Thank you. Your solution helped.  It was in fact a matter of working through the errors to successfully load the dataset. It seems as though "string" is less error prone than the other data type schema options.  The dataset is now loaded, but I'm curious whether you have any suggestions on how best to load date fields.  For example, the format "01/01/2014", which I assumed was a timestamp, produced an error message. After I changed it from Timestamp to String, it loaded successfully.

Comment: Timestamps should be specified in the format described here: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/timestamp. The reason that dates like "01/02/2014" are not allowed is because they are ambiguous; for instance, Americans read this as January 2nd, 2014, while Europeans read it as February 1, 2014.